# How to calculate pandas data frame by date

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Nmc.png)

I want date new column (Output) from `df2['Date']`.

Condition:   vlookup DEVICE_SN and first over date from `df2['Date']`.

Take simple dataframe by dates.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't really a question. Please read [ask]. And [don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341); instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Please provide the dataset(s) in a reproducible format!

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili are you and the question asker the same person?

Comment: @mozway Yes, unfortunately I can't post. The answer below solved the problem.

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili in a very inefficient way, if you're interested in a potentially better way please provide a sample dataset (it can be dummy) ;)

Comment: Yes :), I need an efficient way. Take any base with date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have used two lambda first to get the list of  greater than dates of each ID, in next lambda I am selecting first dates of each list, in case if will empty list will return 'no'

Code:

```
#Change column type str to date, so you can Compare
df1['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df1['output'] = df1.apply(lambda r: [d for d in df2.loc[df2['ID']==r.ID]['Date'] if d > r.Date], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[0] if x else 'no')
df1
```

Output:

```
    ID      Date            output
0   11  2022-05-27  2022-06-11 00:00:00
1   22  2022-01-12  no
2   33  2022-03-01  2022-06-28 00:00:00
3   44  2018-07-19  no
4   55  2018-10-11  no
```